# Tight upper back when running on a treadmill

Tags: exercise, cardiology, asthma, asthma-inhalors

When I go to the Gym and do running on a treadmill I get a tightness across my upper back when I run at 9km/h or more. It's worth noting that I have asthma and use the Brown preventer inhaler and the Blue relief inhaler.

Is it possible that it's my asthma kicking up that's causing my problem? I naturally worry about this sort of stuff as obviously, I don't want it to be anything heart related. I have booked an appointment with my GP but the earliest date they had for me was 1st June, which I've agreed to.

Should I dial it down a notch or two for the time being?

Andy